# Помогите грамотно построить массив

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Из формы поступают данные которые надо отпарсить регуляряркой. В итоге получается массив вида

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Оружие [12]  F
            [1] => Зачаровать Оружие
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 
            [4] => F
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Оружие [12]  F
            [1] => Зачаровать Оружие
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 
            [4] => F
        )
```

Мне же нужно получить массив вида

```
Array
(
    [Зачаровать Оружие] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Оружие [11] (x2)  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Оружие
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 2
            [4] => VP
        )

    [Зачаровать Обувь] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Обувь [11]  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Обувь
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => VP
        )

    [Зачаровать Поножи] => Array
        (
            [0] => Зачаровать Поножи [11]  VP
            [1] => Зачаровать Поножи
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 
            [4] => VP
        )
```

Другими словами чтобы каждая категория вещи содержала в себе подкатегорию вещей которая относится к основной категории.Я реализовал кое какой вариант,но получилось много дублированного кода,подскажите как можно реализовать попроще.

```
function parseInfo($data,$category) {
        $matches = array();

        switch($category){
            case "charki" :
                $pattern = "/(Зачаровать\s\D{1,8})\s\[(\d{1,2})\].{1,3}?(\d{1,2})?.{1,3}?([PVFERUL]+)/u";break;
        }

        preg_match_all($pattern,$data,$found,PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach($found as $item){
            $itemCat = $item[1];
            $thing = $item[1]." ".$item[2]." ".$item[4];

            if(isset($matches[$itemCat])){
                if(isset($matches[$itemCat][$thing])){

                }else{
                    $matches[$itemCat][$thing] = $item; 
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($matches[$itemCat][$thing])){

                }else{
                    $matches[$itemCat][$thing] = $item; 
                }
            }
        }

        return $matches;
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример входящей строки(или строк) для возможности проверки Вашей регулярки.

Comment: Зачаровать Обувь [11]  F   (Масса: 0.1) 
Развернуть/свернутьДолговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 11
Действует на:
• Защита от колющего урона: +2
• Защита от рубящего урона: +4
• Защита от дробящего урона: +2


Зачаровать Поножи [11]  F   (Масса: 0.1) 
Развернуть/свернутьДолговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
• Уровень: 11
Действует на:
• Мф. против увертывания (%): +4
• Защита от магии: +1
• Защита от магии огня: +2
• Защита от колющего урона: +2
• Защита от дробящего урона: +1
• Защита от режущего урона: +1
• Защита от магии воды: +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Как бы это сделал я](http://ideone.com/P3oJ1m)** (не исправляя регулярки):

```
function parseInfo($data, $category) {
    $matches = array();
    $found = array();

    switch ($category) {
        case "charki":
            $pattern_parts = array(
                # Выбрать 1-8 НЕ цифр. Назначить рез-ту ключ "item".
                'item' => '(?<item>\D{1,8})',

                # Внутри "[]" выбрать 1-2 цифры. Назначить рез-ту ключ "category".
                'category' => '\[(?<category>\d{1,2})\]',

                # Не группировать содержимое "()".
                # Найти внутри "()" букву "x" и выбрать после нее 1-2 цифры.
                # Назначить рез-ту ключ "x".
                'multiplier' => '(?:\(x(?<x>\d{1,2})\))?',

                # Найти одну букву из списка "PVFERUL". Назначить рез-ту ключ "mode".
                'mode' => '(?<mode>[PVFERUL]+)'
            );

            # Склеиваем части паттерна, вставляя между значениями \s*
            $pattern = '@Зачаровать' . join('\s*', $pattern_parts) . '@u';
            break;
    }

    preg_match($pattern, $data, $found);

    foreach ($found as $k => $v) {
        # Интересуют только заданные нами именованные ключи
        if (!is_int($k)) {
            # Если 'multiplier' пуст - присваиваем ему 1
            # Все ключи обрабатываем функцией 'trim'
            $matches[$k] = ($k === 'multiplier' && empty($v)) ? 1 : trim($v); 
        }
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

**Тесты:**

```
$db = array();
$text = 'Зачаровать Обувь [11] F (Масса: 0.1)
Развернуть/свернутьДолговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
Уровень: 11
Действует на:
Защита от колющего урона: +2
Защита от рубящего урона: +4
Защита от дробящего урона: +2
Зачаровать Поножи [11] F (Масса: 0.1)
Развернуть/свернутьДолговечность: 0/1
Требуется минимальное:
Уровень: 11
Действует на:
Мф. против увертывания (%): +4
Защита от магии: +1
Защита от магии огня: +2
Защита от колющего урона: +2
Защита от дробящего урона: +1
Защита от режущего урона: +1
Защита от магии воды: +1';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $temp = parseInfo($line, $category = "charki");
    if (!empty($temp)) {
        $db[] = $temp;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($db); echo "</pre>";
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => Обувь
            [category] => 11
            [multiplier] => 1
            [mode] => F
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => Поножи
            [category] => 11
            [multiplier] => 1
            [mode] => F
        )

)
```

Comment: Пока писал ответ, изменились условия. В процессе исправления...

Comment: Пример очень интересный,только поясните пожалуйста зачем регулярку разбивать на части,что это нам дает в итоге?

Comment: Чтобы читаемость повысить. Сравните:  

    @Зачаровать(?P<item>\D{1,8})\s*\[(?P<category>\d{1,2})\]\s*(?:\(x(?P<multiplier>\d{1,2})\))?\s*(?P<mode>[PVFERUL]+)@u

Comment: +вы сходу назначаете имена индексам,вот это очень удобно,так как раньше мне приходилось опять же пробегаться по массиву и назначать имена,было очень неудобно!

Comment: Разобрался я в вашем коде и что к чем,но саму задачу он не решает

Comment: Как именно это выражается? Подробнее опишите проблему, я исправлю свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот таким путем.Если можно проще и эффективнее прошу подсказать

```
public $patternParts = array(
                'category' => '/(?<category>Зачаровать\s\D{1,8})',
                'level' => '\[(?<level>\d{1,2})\]',
                'quantity' => '(?:\(x(?<quantity>\d{1,2})\))?',
                'quality' => '(?<quality>[PVFERUL]+)/u'
    );

    function parseInfo($dataForm){

        $matches = array();

        $pattern = join("\s*",$this->patternParts);
        preg_match_all($pattern,$dataForm,$found,PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach($found as $item){
            if($item['quantity'] == ""){
                $item['quantity'] = 1;
            }

            $thing = trim($item['category']." ".$item['level']." ".$item['quality']);
            $category = trim($item['category']);

            if(!isset($matches[$category][$thing])){
                $matches[$category][$thing] = $item;
            }else{
                $matches[$category][$thing]['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        return $matches;
    }
```

Результат

```
 [Зачаровать Кольцо] => Array
            (
                [Зачаровать Кольцо  11 P] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Зачаровать Кольцо [11]  P
                        [category] => Зачаровать Кольцо 
                        [1] => Зачаровать Кольцо 
                        [level] => 11
                        [2] => 11
                        [quantity] => 2
                        [3] => 
                        [quality] => P
                        [4] => P
                    )

                [Зачаровать Кольцо  12 VP] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Зачаровать Кольцо [12] (x7)  VP
                        [category] => Зачаровать Кольцо 
                        [1] => Зачаровать Кольцо 
                        [level] => 12
                        [2] => 12
                        [quantity] => 7
                        [3] => 7
                        [quality] => VP
                        [4] => VP
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Правда ключи ненужные не отбросил,но это поправлю.Интересует мнение самого способа.